# if $h(x) = f[g(x)]$, then prove that $\nabla h(a) = \sum_{k=1}^n D_k f(b)~ \nabla g_k(a)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If $h(x)=f[g(x)],$ where $g=(g_1,\cdots, g_n)$ is a vector field differentiable at $a$ and $
f$ is a scalar field differentiable at $b=g(a)$. Then prove that $$\nabla h(a) = \sum_{k=1}^n D_k f(b)~ \nabla g_k(a)$$

EDIT:
If $h(x)=f[g(x)],$ where $g=(g_1,\cdots, g_n)$ is a vector field differentiable at $a$ and $
f$ is a scalar field differentiable at $b=g(a)$. Then prove that $$\nabla h(a) = \sum_{k=1}^n D_k f(b)~ \nabla g_k(a)$$

**Attempt:**

By the answer below  :

> $\nabla h=(\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_1},...,\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_n})$, where
>
> $$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_1}=D_1 f\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_1}+D_2 f\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x_2}+...$$
>   $$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_2}=D_1 f\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_2}+D_2 f\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x_2}+...$$

**Question** : Now, $D_1 f = \partial f/\partial x_1$.

> But, by the chain rule : $h(x) = f [ g(x) ] \implies \partial h / \partial x =  f_{x_1}(b). g_{x_1}(a)$ . Hence, I am not able to understand how the above expression came.

Could someone please tell me how the above expression came?

Thank you very much for your help in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do $h'(a) = \nabla h(a) \circ a$ because $h$ is a scalar and $a$ is a vector. Write $h(x)$ as

$$h(x)=f(g_1(x),g_2(x),...,g_n(x))$$

Then $\nabla h=(\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_1},...,\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_n})$, where

$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_1}=D_1 f\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_1}+D_2 f\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x_2}+...$$
$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_2}=D_1 f\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_2}+D_2 f\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x_2}+...$$

$$...$$

There are $n$ components like this. Pick the first terms in each component, that would be the first term in the sum of the right hand side; second terms make the second term on the right hand side, and so on.

The chain rule:

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial r}$$

In your case, $h$ is the $F$, $g_1,g_2,g_3$ are $x,y,z$, and $x_1,x_2,..$ are the $r,\theta$.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tell me how we got to this relation. $$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_1}=D_1 f\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_1}+D_2 f\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x_2}+...$$

Comment: This is by chain rule. In general, given that $F=F(x,y,z)$ and $x=x(r,\theta),y=y(r,\theta),z=z(r,\theta)$, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial r}$. Same rule works for $\theta$.

Comment: Oh okay.. But, isn't there just one variable $\rightarrow x$ here?

Comment: Isn't x a vector?

Comment: I am not sure actually. How do we know if it's or not?

Comment: I believe when it says "vector field", that means the variable is a vector. Also when it asks you to show gradient of h, it means the $a$ is a vector.

Comment: Oh okay. I am just a little confused about the chain rule part  . Could you explain in just a little more detail in your answer above? Thanks.

Comment: $D_1 = \partial f / \partial _{x_1}$ right? Then, what is playing the role of $r,\theta$ etc here?

Comment: Thanks. Could you have a look at my edited question. There I have specified what's actually confusing me. by the chain rule : $h(x) = f [ g(x) ] \implies \partial h / \partial x =  f_{x_1}(b). g_{x_1}(a)$ . Hence, I am not able to understand how the above expression came.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much, I guess, I am just having a bad day today. Thanks again!